# Tableau to calculate occurrence of row variable

Tags: tableau-api, formulas

Trying to figure out tableau calculated fields:

I would like to calculate the occurrence of a row variable. Example:

```
 Fruit  | Occurrence   
 Apple  | 2  
 Apple  | 2 
 Orange | 1 
 Banana | 1
```

Occurrence should be the calculated field which in Excel would be =COUNTIF([fruit]=[@fruit])

What's the equivalent syntax for Tableau?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take in consideration that if you use "FIXED" the filters won`t wot
I suggest to use "INCLUDE"

{INCLUDE[Fruit] : COUNT([Fruit])}

Answer (score 0):

My solution works with `WINDOW` calculations. Also, it requires data disaggregation: [Tableau online documentation](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_aggregation_disaggregatingdata.html)

[image: Data source and worksheet arrangement]

Code for discrete **Calculation2** (Compute using **PANE DOWN**):

```
RUNNING_COUNT(ATTR([Fruit]))
```

Code for discrete **Calculation3** (Compute using **PANE DOWN**):

```
WINDOW_MAX([Calculation2])
```

Whether or not this still works when you shuffle around the values in the data source, I do not know. You would need sorting for the Fruit column then, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised the right answer is:

```
{FIXED [Fruit] : COUNT([Fruit])}
```

Where fixed creates a set array filtering the all rows containing the current row's same variable.